# Adding WSRM AtMostOnce assertion in WSDL file

Tags: soap, wsdl

I've spent quite a few hours reading up on implementing a specific WSRM policy, the AtMostOnce attribute, to prevent duplication of soap messages. Google brought me to several pages in Red Hat's and Oracle's sites, but it seems all I can really find are one of two things on any page I look at-

1. A snippet of code showing just the policy brackets, and a bunch of omitted code in between assuming the reader will get the point (I don't :/ ).
2. A standard example of a WSDL file (defined types, services, ports, bindings, and messages), and then a little bit of text saying what ReliableMessaging is used for, plus the various assertions related to it, and a statement synonmous with "now I'm sure you don't need an example on how to put it all together, so have fun k thnx bye."

All I ask is if someone could please just provide a very simple WSDL example, no code excluded, that implements the AtMostOnce assertion for all messages. Just assume there are only two messages, such as getStuffRequest and getStuffResponse.
Either that or tell me where it is I'm horribly wrong, and perhaps what you consider to be a good resource for learning how to do this correctly.

Comment: I'm curious. Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm dealing with WS-RM right now, and I can't believe how convoluted the whole thing is.

Answer (score 0):

In the Metro download, there are samples:
samples/ws-rm/javaone-2006-demo
search for RMDemo.wsdl
<wsp:ExactlyOne>